# Get screen size in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

It seems in Android there are two ways to get screen width & height:

The 1st way:

```
 WindowManager windowManager =
                (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        //We get width and height in pixels here
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;
```

The 2nd way is:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
//We get width and height in pixels here
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Both ways get screen width and height in pixels. So, I get a bit confused about the following two questions:

Q1. What are the differences between these two screen sizes theoritically?

Q2. Why google provide two ways to get screen size? I think there must be a reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about those two Classes

Window Manager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html

Resources
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html

Window Manager gets screen width and height by getting the width and height of display that the window manager instance is managing including secondary display.

Getting width and height from Resources return the current display metrics and the objects should be treated as Read Only.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) about `DisplayMetrics`:

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.

It seems that the `DisplayMetrics` class provides you with basic *hardware* display information. It does not care about any system UI components that may (or may not) be present.

While the [Display](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) class is more extended and takes the things mentioned above into account.

To answer your question:

```
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

will provide you with absolute values, i.e. you will always get 1080/1920 on a full HD display.

The description of the `getSize()` method is pretty much self-explanatory:

> [...] The size returned by this method does not necessarily represent
>   the actual raw size (native resolution) of the display. The returned
>   size may be adjusted to exclude certain system decoration elements
>   that are always visible. [...]

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMetrics` is a **data** object which best describes the details of the current display, including `widthPixels`, `heightPixels`, `xDpi`, `yDpi`, `density`, `densityDpi` and `scaledDensity`.

`Display` is a more **logical** object which performs the logical operations behind finding these parameters. For example, `Display` can be used to extract `DisplayMetrics` like so:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(metrics); // metrics will now be populated with the required data.
```

*Note:* The above code is, in essence, how Android generates the `DisplayMetrics` instance inside the `Resources` object.

I most often use `DisplayMetrics`, but both options should work just fine.